# Cleaning lenses with ultrasonic technology

Tags: equipment-protection, cleaning

I recently discovered ultrasonic technology and one of the first uses I thought about is cleaning whole lenses - with the appropriate cleaning solution instead of tap water, of course.

Is anybody aware whether it is safe and/or effective to clean the entire lens assembly with this technique?

Could molded lenses benefit from this?

Comment: Are you talking about single lens elements or entire assembled lenses?

Comment: @Blrfl I'm talking about the entire lens. I'll edit the question

Comment: Probably not a good idea unless you typically clean your gear [this way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrdkFXsr5Us).  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modern quality camera lens consists of multiple individual lenses mounted in a tube. Some are spaced apart and some are cemented together. Likely a quality lens barrel contains a tiny motor for focusing and one for adjusting the working diameter (aperture). A motorized lash-up likely has electronic circuits and connections that couple the lens to the camera body.

Ultrasonic systems can be used to clean many things but I think immersing a complex lens barrel in some solvent and applying ultrasound is a bad idea. Consider that oils and grease is present to keep the moving parts well lubricated. On the other hand, an ultrasound clearing system might be helpful when working with individual lens elements during assembly and repair.